# How to drill down multiple levels in dired mode in emacs

Tags: emacs

suppose I have the following ONE file under

src/scala/com/example/

```
src/scala/com/example/test.scala
```

and now I am under src folder in dired. Now I have to click multiple times to locate test.scala. But since there is only one file, is it possible to go to the most deep level where there is more than 1 files, of there is only one file, then go to the most deep level folder?  I find IDEA IDE have that function, If I click a folder, then it will expand the folder all the way down to the most deep folder with at least 2 sub folders. It doesn't make sense to click a folder, get a single folder, then click that single folder, etc.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Are you trying, as you say, to **find** file `test.scala` under `src`? Or are you just asking how to open directory `src/scala/com/example/` directly?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options which do not do exactly this but fulfil some of the same use cases. Firstly tools like `ido.el` will let you move to subdirectories very quickly. Another very powerful tool is `M-x find-dired` which runs find and dumps the results into dired. In your case, invoking `M-x find-dired` with all the defaults will search from `src/` downwards listing all the files (which will include `test.scala` as well as the directories).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to **locate** a file named `test.scala` somewhere under directory `src` then use command `locate-file`.

If you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) then you can use multi-command [`icicle-locate-file`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#FindFilesAnywhere), which is similar but lets you *match any part(s)* of the file name or its path (i.e., the full, absolute file name). Matching can be fuzzy, regexp, substring, prefix,...